# how i can validate checkbox with javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm new in java script.
i want to validate input with type of check box.
i used below code for validation.

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="accept" id="accept" />
    
</form>
```

```js
    
            function checkForm(form) {
                alert('hello');
                if (form.terms!=check) {
                    alert("Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions");
                    form.terms.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
```

```html
 <form name="form1" id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
 
<input class="farsi-font" type="checkbox" name="terms" value="accept" id="accept" style="color: #000" runat="server" />

 </form>
```

however i get alert("Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions");" the form will post to database.and validation just alert to user and didn't prevent form post.any body can help me ?
thank

Comment: Note that you can mark inputs, including checkbox inputs, as required. Also note that using HTML handler attributes (e.g. `onsubmit`) will lead to pain, pain, pain. Use `.addEventListener` in JavaScript instead.

Comment: @JaredSmith thank for your solution, it was helpful

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please accept my answer (green checkmark next to my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where that code came from, but here's how I'd do it:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="accept" id="accept" required />
```

Note the addition of the required attribute.

```
document.querySelector('#accept').setCustomValidity('Please accept the terms and conditions');
```

Now when the user submits the form it will display your message if the box is not checked, the form will not submit. You can test this by placing a `console.log` or `debugger` statement in your submit handler:

```
// Note that as I said in the comments, attaching the handler
// this way is preferable to using the onsubmit HTML attribute.
document.querySelector('#form1').addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
  console.log('stop the presses!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<form onsubmit="return checkForm(event, this);">
  <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="accept" />
</form>
```

JS

```
function checkForm(event, form) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!form.terms.checked) {
    alert("Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

**EDIT:**

To submit the form using only html, you can have the following approaches.

With an input inside the form

```
<form onsubmit="return checkForm(event, this);">
  <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="accept" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit the form" />
</form>
```

With a button outside it. (Now the form must have an id)

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return checkForm(event, this);">
  <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="accept" />
</form>
<button type="submit" form="myForm">Submit the form</button>
```

Comment: dear Alyson,when i use code that you suggest, the submit button did not work, do you have any idea for this problem?

Comment: The submit button is an `<input type="submit" value="Submit the form" />` or something like this? I will edit the answer with more examples on how submit the form.